# Delete lines from pattern match backwards

Tags: command-line, sed, grep, csv

I have a CSV file that I need to parse, but the first `n` lines of this file are worthless garbage.

Fortunately, I know the proper header line starts with `foo`, and that *every* line before the first appearance of `foo` at position 0 can be deleted.

**tl;dr** How do I make this

```
an unknown
number of lines
with worthless junk
that's breaking
my CSV parsing
foo,this,is,the,header,line,always,starts,with,foo
[ legit records to follow ]
```

Turn into this

```
foo,this,is,the,header,line,always,starts,with,foo
[ legit records to follow ]
```

I am expecting a `sed`-powered response to be the right course of action, but any solution that I can run from the command line is sufficient.

Comment: `sed '/^foo/,$!d'` ?

Comment: Or with the opposite logic `sed -n '/^foo/,$p'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments and further research, here's what ultimately worked for me

```
sed -i '/^foo/,$!d' path/to/file
```

Answer (score 2):

This will print everything after foo, inclusive:

```
sed -n '/foo/,$p' file
```

You can pipe it to another file or add the -i parameter to rewrite your file

Comment: This works, but for my purposes I'd rather not process the remainder. That's going to far bigger than the header.